# Update 1 record at a time with a x min delay between each record update

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I understand that I can use a 'Wait' in a process to create a delay; however, I need to delay between each RECORD update and not between each ACTION on the entire dataset.

Simply: if i have 100 records and want to update record 001, wait 5 mins, then update record 002, then wait 5 minutes... update record 100. (I have a flag to identify records that already have been updated)

Comment: can you explain how you launch these workflows? on demand, on a condition with child workflows?

Comment: select records and then run on demand

Comment: Does you workflow do anything else than update of record?

Answer (score 0):

Because you launch the workflows on demand, is not possible to set a delay between each record you selected.

A possible solution is to write a console application that will retrieve the records and launch the workflows with the delay.

Something like this:

```cs
EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(retrieveQuery);
foreach (Entity result in results.Entities)
{
    ExecuteWorkflowRequest requestExecuteWorkflow = new ExecuteWorkflowRequest();
    ExecuteWorkflowResponse responseExecuteWorkflow = new ExecuteWorkflowResponse();
    requestExecuteWorkflow.WorkflowId = workflow.Id; // Workflow Guid;
    requestExecuteWorkflow.EntityId = result.Id;
    responseExecuteWorkflow = (ExecuteWorkflowResponse)service.Execute(requestExecuteWorkflow);
    Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000 * 60);
}
```